# Apache2 failed to start failed to start LSB

Tags: server, apache2, php

While I was working with Laravel, phpMyAdmin didn't work and I got `error 2002`.

I reinstalled everything (`apache2`, `php` and `phpmyadmin`), but a problem occured with `apache2` and it cannot start anymore.

Here is the error:

```
    ● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-07-07 03:11:31 EET; 6ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 4035 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 07 03:11:31 Alex apache2[4035]:  *
Jul 07 03:11:31 Alex apache2[4035]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Jul 07 03:11:31 Alex apache2[4035]: Output of config test was:
Jul 07 03:11:31 Alex apache2[4035]: apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /e...ry
Jul 07 03:11:31 Alex apache2[4035]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Jul 07 03:11:31 Alex apache2[4035]: The Apache error log may have more info...n.
Jul 07 03:11:31 Alex systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, c...=1
Jul 07 03:11:31 Alex systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jul 07 03:11:31 Alex systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 07 03:11:31 Alex systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-...'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your .conf file in line 140.

That's what the error tells you.

You can see which .conf file it is if you use the `-l` like listed in the last line of that message.

```
systemctl status apache2.service -l
```